# Why is Patry so powerful, if he isnt the true elf leader?

Tags: black-clover

Patry impersonated the true elf leader, but he isn't him. Yet, he was able to defeat a magic emperor, and he was shown to be very powerful. Why is Patry so powerful, if he isn't the true elf leader?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can call him so powerful.  As an elf, he is more powerful than human; we all know that.
He is powerful because of 3 main reasons:

> 1. ELF POWER
> 2. William Vengeance body
> 3. four-leaf clover grimoire

1. We all about elves magic power so no discussion.
2. He got the most powerful human body of William Vengeance who ranked just after wizard king in clover kingdom magic night rankings(all the clover people recognize him as next wizard king), I think this is the main reason. All those elves who got magic knight squad captain bodies are powerful.
3. we all know the four-leaf clover grimoire considered the most powerful.